# Word Extraction C

Tags: c

I want to extract the words from a file (and later, from console input), count their appearances and store them in my Word structure:

```
typedef struct cell{
        char *info; /* word itself */
        int nr;     /* number of appearances of the word *
        }*Word;
```

This structure will be allocated dynamically for as many words are contained in the file. Consider this function:

```
void Word_Allocation (Word* a) /* The function that allocates space for one structure */
```

My questions are:

1. How do I correctly open a file and read it line by line?
2. How do I correctly store words and number of appearances in my structure?

Comment: Do you really need to read line by line when analyzing words? Why not read word by word?

Comment: Or that, didn't think of it but as long as i get what i want why not :)

Comment: there is no code here showing what you have tried.  You're basically asking people to write your homework for you.

Comment: So you can use scanf("%s") (or better a safer equivalent such as e.g. "%128s" ) to read a word at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Your allocator function should return a `Word*` and receive a size to allocate for the word itself. Something like this, perhaps:

```
Word * Word_Allocation (size_t size) {
    Word *w = malloc(sizeof(*w));
    if (w) w->info = malloc(size);
    if (!w->info)
    {
        free(w);
        w = NULL;
    }
    return w;
}
```

You can read a word at a time with:

```
#define STR(x) #x
enum {MAX_BUF = 100};
char buf[MAX_BUF];
fscanf(infile, "%" STR(MAX_BUF) "s", buf);
```

And then `strlen(buf)+1` is the size to pass to `Word_Allocation`. Or you can pass `buf` and have `Word_Allocation` call `strlen` and copy the data over.

Comment: Thanks for the fixup, LihO and @perror! (almost missed your contribution. good job!)

Answer (score 1):

1. As for file io, [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILE/) is the basics.
2. As for the algorithm, since you are not using C++, so `map` is not available which is trivial for this problem. A straightforward solution in C might be:

   1. Allocated an array of `cell` and read in words
   2. sort the array on `char *info`.
   3. count